# Finding the least square fit for 3 parameters in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, least-squares

I know how to find least square for $y = mx+b$ when we have two parameters. But this question has $3$ parameters, am trying to think of how to approach it but so far no success, I can't find any formulars for it. Help me out.

[image]

Comment: You would like the curve to go through $(-3,9)$, yielding the equation $a-3b+9c=9$. Do the same with the other 4 points to get a system of 5 linear equations in the three unknowns $a,b,c$. That's a single matrix equation $Av=w$. The normal equation is $A^tAv=A^tw$. Got that?

Comment: THANK-YOU very very much, it was kind of hard to see right away. but now I believe I can go on.

Comment: When you get it done, you can write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: Least squares problem: find the line through the origin in $\mathbb{ℝ}^{3}$:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026451/least-squares-problem-find-the-line-through-the-origin-in-mathbbr3/2180128#2180128