# Solving Non-linear Overdetermined System of Equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, regression, nonlinear-system

I have a problem similar to [The best fit for variables in a number of equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754099/the-best-fit-for-variables-in-a-number-of-equations) but my system is nonlinear i.e.:

$$A_1 * X * Y = B_1$$

$$A_2 * X * Y = B_2$$

$$...$$

$$A_n * X * Y = B_n$$

Are there any methods to solve this system for $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: If the asterisks represent multiplication, then no, since you just have that

$$XY = \frac{A_1}{B_1} = \cdots = \frac{A_n}{B_n} \equiv \text{constant}$$

If $XY=3$ for instance, you don't know whether $X = 3$ and $Y=1$ or $X = \sqrt 3= Y$ or any other strange arrangement

Comment: @PrincessEev Yes it it multiplication. This is what I was thinking - thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reposting comment as answer, owing to clarification and so the post is properly marked as being answered.*

---

No, since you just have that
$$XY=\frac{A_1}{B_1}= \cdots =\frac{A_n}{B_n} \equiv \text{constant}$$
If $XY=3$ for instance, you don't know whether $X=3$ and $Y=1$ or $X=Y=\sqrt 3$ or any other factorization.